# Can Java print text (letter by letter) into the command prompt?

Tags: java

```
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        TimerTask task = new TimerTask(){
            int letter = 0;
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if(letter<StatementInput.length()){
                    System.out.print(StatementInput.charAt(letter));
                    letter++;
                }else{timer.cancel();}
            }
        };
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task,0,100 );
    }
```

I'm trying to print out text one character at a time, with a small interval between each letter. When I try Thread.sleep or the above code, it won't print smoothly, the text comes out in bunches. Is there any way for me to smoothen it out?

I am running the code in intellij and am new to Java.

EDIT: Here's the full source code:

```
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class test {
    public static void statement(String StatementInput) throws InterruptedException {
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        TimerTask task = new TimerTask(){
            int letter = 0;
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if(letter<StatementInput.length()){
                    System.out.print(StatementInput.charAt(letter));
                    letter++;
                }else{timer.cancel();}
                System.out.flush();
            }
        };
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task,0,100 );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        test.statement("Hello World!!!!");

    }
}
```

Comment: try `System.out.flush()` after each `print`?

Comment: I tried it, but nothing changes.

Comment: please include you `main` method, for us to copy code and reproduce the issue.

Comment: i ran you code and working fine, each char is displayed at fixed interval.

Comment: Does it have to do with what version of Java I'm using? I'm using 11 Eclipse Temurin 11.0.14. Does it have to do with me running it Itellij?

Comment: if you doubt the ide, just run from command line. i'm using intellij and jdk11.